# Python  литература на русском

Tags: python, pygame, pygtk

Есть ли литература на русском про PyGtk, PyGame, Python opengl?

Answer (score 1):

Разве что

- http://python.su/tag/pygtk/
- http://translated.by/you/python-pygame-introduction/into-ru/

Answer (score 0):

Касаемо PyGTK, сколько не искал - на русском языке только небольшие мануалы из серии "how-to", "Hello world", справочников нет вообще.
Подробный материал только на "вражеском". И то, не все описано.